# Как игнорировать первый символ в инпут при клике на него?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook

Я создаю компонент чипс. Я ввожу текст в инпут поле и при нажатии клавиши "запятая"(русская "б") я создаю чипс. Как мне сделать что-бы при пустом инпуте (когда я не вел никакой текст) и нажал запятую, ничего не делать? Просто игнорировать запятую если я кликаю на неё при пустом инпуте (просто нужно ничего не делать).

Сейчас при пустом инпуте и нажатии на запятую создается пустой чипс:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мой чипс компонент в `codesandbox` https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-glitter-dkh25?file=/src/App.js

Вот моя функция создания чипса:

```
  const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
    if (event.key === "," && input.split('"').length % 2 === 1) {
      event.preventDefault();
      setChips([...chips, event.target.value]);
      setInput("");
    }
  };
```

Comment: if (input.length === 0) return

Comment: Спасибо, Алексей